# syntax error at or near "AS" (case when statement)

Tags: sql, postgresql

As in the title the error occures in:

```
CASE
WHEN hl.brnd_fmly_desc_txt <> null THEN 'HERO BRANDS'
ELSE NULL
END AS hero_brnd_fmly_desc_txt,
```

...

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT h.brnd_fmly_desc_txt, h.brnd_fmly_id
FROM ext_ce.hero_brands_list h 
GROUP BY h.brnd_fmly_desc_txt, h.brnd_fmly_id) AS hl
on c.brnd_fmly_id = hl.brnd_fmly_id
```

The code is too complex to paste it all. I am going to left join  h.brnd_fmly_desc_txt to existing query and if the condition is met: c.brnd_fmly_id = hl.brnd_fmly_id call the values as 'HERO BRANDS'

This is Postgre Sql 8.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: That subquery needs no GROUP BY. SELECT DISTINCT removes all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are getting *that* error.  But your logic is wrong.  The expression `<> null` always returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.  The logic you want is:

```
(CASE WHEN hl.brnd_fmly_desc_txt IS NOT NULL THEN 'HERO BRANDS'
 END) AS hero_brnd_fmly_desc_txt
```

The `ELSE` is not needed.  You can leave it in, but it is redundant because the default value is `NULL`.